# use expression as ng-class in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class

I have unordered list in which I want different different class for each li which will be dynamic.

my code is

```
$scope.className = ['clr1','clr2','clr3','clr4','clr5'];
```

My Html :

```
  <div>
        <ul>
         <li  ng-repeat="item in mainitem"  ng-style="{color: color[$index]}" >
              <span  ng-class="{className [$index]}">{{ item.name}}</span>  // At this line I ahve added dynamic class but its not working
          </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

This is not applied class as per classname array !!

Is there any issue with this code ? Thanks for helping !!

Comment: Why not use CSS class with `:nth-child(n+1)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks !! can you pls update with code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `[]` instead of `{}`

```
 <div>
        <ul>
         <li  ng-repeat="item in mainitem"  ng-style="{color: color[$index]}" >
              <span  ng-class="[className[$index]]">{{ item.name}}</span>  
          </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

for example of working see this codepen [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQvYJx)

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee i provide a link below

Comment: Its not adding class !!

Comment: `$scope.className = ['clr1','clr2','clr3','clr4','clr5'];` - but I don't see any of those classes declared in the CSS in your CodePen

Comment: Hey Thanks its seems working this way !! Thank you very much !!

Comment: Not provided in CSS but its getting the classes

Comment: Working which way? Please tell us, to help future readers of the question.

Comment: <span  ng-class="[className[$index]]">{{ item.name}}</span>  

This is working fine

Answer (score 0):

As the code is posted in the question, you are missing an opening brace when evaluating the class name

```
<span  ng-class="{className [$index]}">{{ item.name}}</span>
```

should be

```
<span  ng-class="{{className [$index]}">{{ item.name}}</span>
```

when it doesn't evaluate, you will end up with no class at all

Comment: Then there is a second problem (which I will look for). But the error which I pointed out still has to be corrected.

Comment: Yes I missed it !! Although I am using second one itself !! But its not adding class